# What is the C# equivalent of Java List.of()?

Tags: c#

I need a fast way to create immutable Lists in one line just like Java's `List.of()`, but in C#. What's the equivalent to this syntax?

```
List<String> strings = List.of("first", "second");
```

Comment: have you tried a _search engine_? did you find out about the class named [Immutable List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-5.0)? (also, whoever flagged the duplicate: that is _not_ a duplicate of this question....)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann `List<String>` is not immutable in Java, so I don't think the OP is looking for an immutable collection.

Comment: well, OP explicitly said `immutable Lists`. so it's at least a reasonable assumption (backed by the accepted answer)

Comment: @juharr Whether `List<String>` is immutable in Java, depends on the actual implementation used (`List` is an interface), and `List.of` in fact returns an immutable (unmodifiable) list: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`ImmutableList.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist.create?view=net-5.0)

```
ImmutableList<string> list = ImmutableList.Create("first", "second");
```

You *could* also use [`AsReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly?view=net-5.0) which returns a wrapper for the list:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> readonlyList = new List<string> { "first", "second" }.AsReadOnly();
```

However, as this is just a wrappper you can always modify the underlying list, so it's not truly immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "first", "second" };
```

Comment: that list is in no way immutable - whatever OP actually means by that.